# InstallSheild not writing to registry or ProgramData in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, installshield

I built an installation ine installshield express, and it works fine on windows 7 and windows 10.  But for some reason it is not installing all of the files on windows 8.1.  There is also a registry entry, which is not being written.  I have checked the permissions and no issues there.  Any point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no error in installation, let's assume installation is successful. If it is 64 bit, Check in Wow64 subsystem in registry. for files, search in C:\Program files(X86).

Check event viewer (eventvwr) for error messages if any.

Answer (score 0):

Check for UAC status and Windows Event Viewer(eventvwr) for error logs